# rpm subpackage is not created

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

i am trying to create 2 rpm packages, though the second one has very less operation to do.
I have created this spec file:

```
%define name        @CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME@ 
%define version     @CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION@
%define release     @CPACK_PACKAGE_RELEASE@
%define binarydir   @BINARY_DIR@ 
%define packagedir  @PACKAGE_DIR@ 


#component name - used for the rpm name
%{!?name:%{error:*** Name was not specified! ***}}

# passed as a parameter in the build - the release version 
# e.g OverhaulRelease.MajorRelease.MinorRelease
%{!?version:%{error:*** Version was not specified! ***}}

# passed as a parameter in the build - the 5 digit build number 
%{!?release:%{warn:*** Release was not specified, so Dev build ***} %define release 0}

## we need to redfine this here to avoid the pre-compilation of the python code
%define __os_install_post %{nil}

## disable RPM object stripping so the
## Qt GUI binaries don't get truncated
%define __strip /bin/true

# set up some commonly used variables
%define buildroot @CMAKE_BINARY_DIR@/_CPack_Packages/Linux/RPM/@CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME@
%define prefix %{name}
%define appdir /%{name}
%define _topdir @CMAKE_BINARY_DIR@/_CPack_Packages/Linux/RPM
%define _rpmdir @CMAKE_BINARY_DIR@/_CPack_Packages/Linux/RPM
%define _rpmfilename @CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME@.rpm
%define _unpackaged_files_terminate_build 0 



## Intro ##

Name:           %{name}
Version:        %{version}
Release:        %{release}
Vendor:         %{company}
URL:            %{url}
Packager:       %{company} 
License:        %{copyright}

# Define the other packages that this rpm depends on here
Requires:       bash

Provides:       %{name}


Summary:        %{name} %{version}_%{release}
Group:          Applications/Communications
BuildRoot:      %{buildroot}

%package -n @CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME@_run

## Intro ##

#Name:           %{name}
Version:        %{version}
Release:        %{release}
Vendor:         %{company}
URL:            %{url}
Packager:       %{company} 
License:        %{copyright}

# Define the other packages that this rpm depends on here
Requires:       bash

Provides:       %{name}

Summary:        %{name} %{version}_%{release}
Group:          Applications/Communications
BuildRoot:      %{buildroot}
#Icon:


%define _rpmfilename @CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME@_run.rpm

%description -n @CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME@_run

#%prep
#%build

######## clean ########
#%clean

######## pre-install ########
# Define any pre-install steps here
%pre -n @CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME@_run

######## install ########
%install -n @CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME@_run

# Make the required install directories
# there are made in the buildroot in the local repo,
# but translated when the rpm is installed - removing the buildroot


mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{opt_root}
mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{etc_root}
mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{var_root}


# Copy the required installed files to the buildroot dir to collect the 
# files required for installation
# Also, create any required symbolic links here

######## post-install ########
%post -n @CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME@_run

# Set up the symbolic version directory links
# This should eventually be moved to an enable rpm,
# But for now keep it as a single rpm
/bin/ln -s  %{opt_root} %{opt_link}
/bin/ln -s  %{etc_root} %{etc_link}
/bin/ln -s  %{var_root} %{var_link}

# Do other post install commands here, like starting the required process/services etc


######## pre-uninstall ########
%preun -n @CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME@_run

######## post-uninstall ########
%postun -n @CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME@_run

## FILES ##

# Define user attributes and permissions for files
# List the atcual files and paths as they will look on the installed server
# i.e. without the buildroot prefic

%files -n @CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME@_run

%dir %{opt_root}
%dir %{etc_root}
%dir %{var_root}



%package -n @CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME@_ena


#Name:           %{name}_ena
Version:        %{version}
Release:        %{release}
Vendor:         %{company}
URL:            %{url}
Packager:       %{company} 
License:        %{copyright}

# Define the other packages that this rpm depends on here
Requires:       bash

Provides:       %{name}

Summary:        %{name} %{version}_%{release}
Group:          Applications/Communications
BuildRoot:      %{buildroot}
#Icon:


%define _rpmfilename @CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME@_ena.rpm
%define _unpackaged_files_terminate_build 0 


%description -n @CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME@_ena

#%prep
#%build

######## clean ########
#%clean

######## pre-install ########
# Define any pre-install steps here
%pre -n @CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME@_ena

######## install ########
%install -n @CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME@_ena

mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{var_root}/output
cp    --sparse=never %{binarydir}/stub1 %{buildroot}%{opt_root}/bin/stub1
cp    --sparse=never %{binarydir}/stub2 %{buildroot}%{opt_root}/bin/stub2

######## post-install ########
%post -n @CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME@_ena

# Set up the symbolic version directory links
# This should eventually be moved to an enable rpm,
# But for now keep it as a single rpm
/bin/ln -s  %{opt_root} %{opt_link}
/bin/ln -s  %{etc_root} %{etc_link}
/bin/ln -s  %{var_root} %{var_link}

# Do other post install commands here, like starting the required process/services etc


######## pre-uninstall ########
%preun -n @CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME@_ena

######## post-uninstall ########
%postun -n @CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME@_ena


%files -n @CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME@_ena
```

so i have 2 questions here:
1. only 2 rpms are generated here- the main and the second one, i am expecting 3 the main and the 2 subpackages
2. In the second subpackage if i specify the %install section, rpm build throws error in second %install.

Sorry for posting the detailed spec here: but cant get the exact answer for my problem in few words :)

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: I don't think `%build`, `%install`, etc. get per-package versions. I believe you just have per-package `%package`, `%description` and `%files`. Also I don't believe (unless this has changed since the version I'm using) that `%package`/etc. take `-n` arguments.

Comment: Turns out `%package`/etc. can take `-n` as an argument so I was wrong about that bit. But I still believe only those few sections are duplicated for sub-packages and not the main ones.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but if i want some specific operations that should be part of the sub-package install how can i add it ?

Comment: Specific operations at build time? Like what? debug builds instead of release builds? I don't believe you can do that (and that specific example is what `-debug` split-symbol packages are for.

Comment: operations i meant mkdir/mv/cp etc..

Comment: operations i meant mkdir/mv/cp etc..Anyways i found the solution to my problem, i switched to do this without using CPACK . Hence i made some minor changes like defining my own _topdir,_srcdir, _rpmdir and _blddir, buildroot.The _rpmfilename is not necessary in case of using rpmbuild command. Now iam able to build the package using rpmbuild -bb <specfile> command. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Only two packages are created because you only have two `%files` directives.  One package is created for each distinct `%files` directive in your specfile.  I believe Etan answered your other questions in the comments.